# Using RouterModule to navigate to one component using 2 routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm have a component SportComponent which displays a list of competitions for a sport.
I have defined a Routes array:

```js
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sport/:id', component: SportComponent }
];
```

In my app.html I have defined my routerLinks as:

```html
 <li><a routerLink="/sport/1" routerLinkActive="active">Soccer</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/sport/2">Rugby</a></li>
```

In my SportComponent component, I retrieve the list of competitions for a sport from a webservice and display it in a view. I was doing this in the ngOnInit() method and was working fine when I navigate from a different component to the SportComponent. I would like to know how I can navigate from /sport/1 to /sport/2 or vice versa and retrieve a new list each time? Is there a hook/callback that I could use to achieve this? Or should I reconsider my design??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SportComponent, you need to subscribe to the [ActivatedRoute.params](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#params-anchor) observable. It emits an event each time the params change (i.e. when you first go to /sports/1, and when you switch from /sports/1 to /sports/2).

So, when it emits, go fetch the competitions for the new sport ID, extracted from the Params event.

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
@Component({
  template: `<h1>Sport {{id}}</h1>
    <li><a routerLink="/sport/1" routerLinkActive="active">Soccer</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/sport/2">Rugby</a></li>
  `
})
export class SportComponent { 
  id;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
       this.id = param.id;
      //
      // do your action to get new list
      //         
    })
  }
}
```

Check this [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/lP6IlBXavRmMJEqeJgSH?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!